# Python: Given List of Dictionaries return average of values based on key if key doesn't exist return none

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm working on a function that takes a list of dictionaries as well as a desired year as input. The function will check if the desired year (key) exists if it does it will calculate the average of the GPA's for that key. If the desired year doesnt exist it will return none. I currently have the problem working for key's that do exists, but not sure how to return none/handle instances where key's dont exist. For senior it calculates the average correctly for all seniors, but not sure how to handle the 2nd function call where junior doesn't exist.

```
Output for senior is correct: 2.19
However it should return none for junior.
```

Comment: It's not complicated.  `if not year:` / `return None` / `else:` / `return avg`.  BTW, the computation of `avg` should be un-indented two spots so it is outside of the loop.  You don't compute the average until you have all the values.  And when you do that, it should be in the part of the `if` that knows `year` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Move `avg` calculation out of loop (no need to calculate for each iteration) and check if `year` is empty, if it is empty return None:

```
def avgGpa(studentDic, desiredYear):
    year = []
    for value in studentDic:
        if value['year'] == desiredYear:
            year.append(value)
    if len(year) == 0:
        return None
    avg = sum(value['GPA'] for value in year) / len(year)
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```py
from statistics import mean, StatisticsError

student_data = [
    {"id": 0, "year": "freshman", "GPA": 0.03},
    {"id": 1, "year": "senior", "GPA": 0.7},
    {"id": 2, "year": "senior", "GPA": 2.77},
    {"id": 3, "year": "sophomore", "GPA": 1.1},
    {"id": 4, "year": "sophomore", "GPA": 1.05},
    {"id": 5, "year": "freshman", "GPA": 0.43},
    {"id": 6, "year": "senior", "GPA": 3.1},
]


def avgGpa(studentDic, desiredYear):
    try:
        return mean(d["GPA"] for d in studentDic if d["year"] == desiredYear)
    except StatisticsError:
        pass


print(avgGpa(student_data, "senior"))
print(avgGpa(student_data, "junior"))
```

Prints:

```
2.19
None
```